# Can't get rid of div line break in CSS

Tags: html, css

I can not get rid of the linebreak between the input field and the submit button in this code example:

http://jsfiddle.net/m4FNx/1/
(using Chrome)

I set all the relevant tags to

```
display:inline-block
```

but it doesn't seem to do what it normally does.

I've been looking too long at it so I can't see the error in there anymore, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: beside "display:inline-block", you have to set the "width" for your div also

Comment: your container for the form isn't wide enough to allow it to be a one-liner. so it's collapsing down the width of the biggest element, which is the input box.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to set a fixed width (which won't always work), add

```
white-space:nowrap;
```

to your `.bubble` div.  This will prevent the contents from wrapping.

Answer (score 2):

Set a width to the .bubble div

```
.bubble {
    width: 320px;
}
```

Comment: This. Then you can remove the 'float:left' and 'display:inline-block' from feature-call-sip and feature-call-sip-button.